# How to add cards in docusaurus site just like implemented in playground page in docusaurus site?

Tags: docusaurus

I want to add cards to my docusaurus v2 site just like in the Playground Page in docusaurus.io/docs/playground. Can someone tell me how to implement it?

Comment: This is the [source code for the playground page](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/docs/playground.mdx) and [this is the component used](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/main/website/src/components/Playground/index.tsx). Try to mess-around with it.

Comment: I tried the source code but it gives me unknown errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution for this one year later, but I had the same question and landed on https://iframely.com/
It's not the cheapest (min. $29/month) but looks great, is well documented and has lots of integrations.

https://embed.ly/ is a cheaper alternative but only has one card style (horizontal) which I didn't like.